# Re-render issues

Tags: visualforce

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

when I put in the phone number and passphrase that don't find a match, I get the message, "Record Not found...Please try your search again"...when I put in a diff number and don't enter the passphrase, I get the validation error, but I also get the Record Not found message. At this point, how do I suppress it/hide it from being displayed. I tried using Re-render on op1 and op2, but that's suppressing the validation errors too....Not sure how the re-render is really working.

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="newOpportunityController">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:messages />
    <apex:pageblock title="Enter Search Criteria" id="pb1">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" >

            <apex:inputField value="{!sacct.phone}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputSecret value="{!sacct.Passphrase__c}" required="true"  />

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <p/>    
        <p/> 

        <apex:outputPanel id="op1">
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showrecord}" id="op2">
                 <apex:outputLabel value="Record Not found...Please try your search again" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">

            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!startPageNext}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!searchAcct}" reRender="op1"  />

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>    

     </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
 public pagereference searchAcct(){
    showrecord=false;
    system.debug ('SEARCH acct info -> '+ sacct);
    resultAcct = accountSearch.search1(sacct);
    if (resultacct !=NULL) {
        system.debug ('retrieved acct info -> '+ resultAcct);
        return null;
    }
    else {
    showrecord=true;
     return searchPageNext();

    }

}
```

Comment: You should also rerender the <apex:pageMessages> element.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to set showrecord=true if only phonenumber and account is valid

so:
 else {
if phonenumber and account is valid then
  {  showrecord=true;}
     return searchPageNext();
    }

It should work.

Good Luck
William